# Reference to type 'ISerializable' claims it is defined in 'mscorelib'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, emgucv, hololens

I am using **EmguCV** in **Unity 5.6.2f1 Personal** to detect faces in a camera stream.
And it works just fine if I'm trying to run it in the built-in Editor/Game Output and there are no Errors in the Console.

However, when I'm trying to build it to Windows Store, specifically HoloLens, I'm getting 4 Errors in the Console:

```
Assets\OpenCVTest.cs(57,11): error CS7069: Reference to type 'ISerializable' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found
Assets\OpenCVTest.cs(57,11): error CS7069: Reference to type 'ICloneable' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found
Assets\OpenCVTest.cs(62,26): error CS7069: Reference to type 'ISerializable' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found
Assets\OpenCVTest.cs(62,26): error CS7069: Reference to type 'ICloneable' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found
```

It seems weird since it works just fine in the built-in preview, but not when I'm trying to export it.

the lines in question are

```
using (Image<Gray, byte> nextFrame = cap.QueryFrame ().ToImage<Gray, byte>()) {

Rectangle[] faces = cascade.DetectMultiScale(nextFrame, 1.4, 1);
```

and according to the line number it refers to `Image` in the one line and `cascade` (which is a `CascadeClassifier`) in the other.
A few google searches for different keywords, including the error-numbers didn't yield any helpful result. Similar questions on here weren't able to help me either, since the surroundings are completely different.

---

Here is my complete code, without all the unnecessary stuff:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class OpenCVTest : MonoBehaviour {

private VideoCapture cap;
private CascadeClassifier cascade;
private int counter;
private int intervall;
private GameObject border;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    counter = 0;
    intervall = 6;
    cap = new VideoCapture (0);
    cascade = new CascadeClassifier ("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
    border = Resources.Load ("Border") as GameObject;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    counter++;
    if (counter >= intervall) {
        counter = 0;
        using (Image<Gray, byte> nextFrame = cap.QueryFrame ().ToImage<Gray, byte>()) {  //ERROR 1
            if (nextFrame != null) {
                Rectangle[] faces = cascade.DetectMultiScale(nextFrame, 1.4, 1);    //ERROR 2

                //remove preivious borders
                var previous = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Face");

                foreach (var box in previous) {
                    Destroy (box.gameObject);
                }

                //instanciate new ones
                foreach (var face in faces) {
                    GameObject newBorder = Instantiate (border);
                    newBorder.transform.position = new Vector3 (face.X / 100f, face.Y / -100f, 10);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

all my EmguCV dll's are in `Assets\Plugins`.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you come with a solution?

Comment: No, i sadly have not found a solution. I'm fact I have sort of given up on this project and moved on.